# Html table cell padding where I only have access to elements inside of the td cell which has to have the background styling

Tags: html, css, datatables

I'm datatable JS so have limited control on the table output but I have managed to add elements inside of the `<td>`

```css
.dataTable {
  border: 1px solid black;
 }

 .dataTable td {
   border: 1px solid #ccc
 } 

/*This cannot be added to the .error-cell*/
.dataTable td:has(.error-cell) {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: #FAC7BE;
  background: #FFF0EE;
  color: #B23015;
  fill: #B23015;
}
```

```html
<table class="dataTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        non error cell
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="error-cell">
            This cell has the error
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        non error cell
      </td>
      <td>
        non error cell
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What this output to is the following:
[image: my current output]

But what I need from the design is padding inside the td to look like this:

[image: what I want it to look like]

Images attached of my current attempt and desired outcome

Comment: Can you put a `margin` on the `span.error-cell`?  Would you be able to update the code snippet in the question to demonstrate the attempt and the problem encountered?

Comment: No I've tried margin but has no effect. Please see the images, I cant seem to get the code snippet to run

Comment: I'm entirely convinced that I know what you want. From your second image it looks like all the cells have some padding and that the `.error-cell` is an element inside the cell. In which case shouldn't you be styling the `.error-cell` rather itself rather than its parent `td`?

Comment: *"Please see the images"* - While pictures can be useful, a picture of output is not the same thing as the code which produces that output.  *"I cant seem to get the code snippet to run"* - Currently the code snippet contains a single table cell, which ultimately contains a single non-existent HTML element.  So it displays nothing.  You can modify it to display as many rows/cells as you like, as well as put content within those cells.

Answer (score 1):

From your second image it looks like all the cells have some padding and that the `.error-cell` is an element inside the cell. In which case you should style the `.error-cell` itself rather than its parent `td`.

Something like:

```css
.dataTable {
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%
}
.dataTable td {
  border:1px solid grey;
  padding:1rem;
}
.dataTable td .error-cell {
  display:block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #FFF0EE;
  color: #B23015;
  padding:0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<table class="dataTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    1
    </td>
      <td>
        <span class="error-cell">
          <a class="info-tooltip" data-html="true" title="This field is required.">
            <my-icon name="interface-warning">!</my-icon>
          </a>
        </span>
      </td>      
    <td>
    3
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If your `td`s don't have any padding and/or you only want this extra padding on this one cell then you can add a margin around `.error-cell`. EG:

```
.dataTable td .error-cell {margin:1rem;}
```

```css
.dataTable {
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%
}
.dataTable td {
  border:1px solid grey;
}
.dataTable td .error-cell {
  display:block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #FFF0EE;
  color: #B23015;
  padding:0.5rem;
  margin:1rem;
}
```

```html
<table class="dataTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    1
    </td>
      <td>
        <span class="error-cell">
          <a class="info-tooltip" data-html="true" title="This field is required.">
            <my-icon name="interface-warning">!</my-icon>
          </a>
        </span>
      </td>      
    <td>
    3
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, yes this is the best solution if you have full access to all elements. I dont so I need to cell space it some how as the background is set to the td and I have to keep it that way

Comment: What elements don't you have access to? I have only changed the CSS. The html remains untouched. What things *can* you change?